# "Зі спеціальним статусом" чи "із спеціальним статусом"?

Tags: прийменники

Який варіант прийменника - *зі* чи *із* - краще застосувати у словосполученні *центральний орган виконавчої влади ... спеціальним статусом*? Законодавчо використовуються обидва варіанти, але, на мою думку, *зі спеціальним статусом* більш відповідає милозвучності української мови.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### § 25. Позиції вживання прийменника З та його варіантів ІЗ, ЗІ (ЗО)

Варіанти **[із, зі (зо)](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf)** вживаємо перед буквами, що передають важкі для вимови збіги приголосних, та для досягнення милозвучності.

> 2. **Із** уживаємо переважно перед буквами, що позначають свистячі та шиплячі звуки (**з, с, ц, ч, ш, шч**) незалежно від закінчення
>    попереднього слова та між буквосполученнями (після них або перед
>    ними): *Перстень виготовлено із золота; Родина із семи душ; Гнат...
>    запріг коні й так їх гнав із села, що вони із шкури вилазили* (М.
>    Стельмах); *Із шовку виготовили вітрила; А вже весна, а вже красна! Із
>    стріх вода капле* (Нар. пісня); *I місив новий заміс із тіста старого*
>    (І. Драч); *Тихович разом із сходом сонця зірвався на рівні ноги* (М.
>    Коцюбинський); *Лист із Бразилії* (І. Франко).

> 3. **Зі** вживаємо, якщо буквосполучення наступного слова має початкові **з, с, ш, шч та ін.**, незалежно від закінчення
>    попереднього слова чи паузи: *Ви зустріли ворога... зі зброєю в руках*
>    (Ю.Яновський); *Балада зі знаком запитання* (І. Драч); *Зі школи на майдан вивалила дітвора* (А. Головко);
>
> У позиції перед деякими
> буквосполученнями варіанти **із** та **зі** можуть бути взаємозамінними, пор.:
> ***Устав разом ІЗ сходом сонця*** і ***Устав разом ЗІ сходом сонця***.

> **Примітка.** Трапляються відхилення від поданих правил уживання прийменника **з** та його варіантів **із**, **зі**, що спричинено вимогами
> ритмомелодики або мовними вподобаннями автора.

То ж, прийменник **із** вжіваємо переважно на початку речення та в середині речення у тих випадках, коли прийменник **зі** вжити неможливо.

Answer (score 2):

Правопис 2019 [має](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf):

3. **Зі** вживаємо, якщо буквосполучення наступного слова має початкові з,
   **с,** ш, шч та ін.,  незалежно від закінчення попереднього слова  чи паузи:  Ви зустріли  ворога...  зі зброєю  в  руках  (Ю. Яновський); Балада  зі знаком запитання  (І. Драч);  Бере  книжку  **зі  с**тола  (Леся  Українка);  Зі  школи  на майдан вивалила дітвора  (А. Головко); Прибув зі Львова.

З правопису бачимо, що "із" перед цими "з, **с,** ш, шч та ін." вживається тоді, коли після цих літер іде голосна, а "зі" — коли приголосна. У вашому випадку приголосна.

Отже, "зі спеціальним статусом".